# Cannot update WordPress to 5.2

Tags: updates, nginx

I am using CentOS 7 (`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`), NGINX 1.15.12, WordPress 5.1

Error

> Update WordPress
> Downloading update from [https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.2-no-content.zip…](https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.2-no-content.zip%E2%80%A6)

> Unpacking the update…

> The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

> Installation Failed

Comment: But what did you do then? Have you checked file and folder permissions and ownership as the error message suggests? Please update your question with your findings regarding file and folder permissions and ownership. Many thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I've set all the files to uid:gid of www-data:www-data (which is the user and group apache is running as) and set all the files permissions to 664 and directories  permissions to 775 (i also tried 644 and 755, and just to see if it would work, I tried 777 for both) and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

All directories should be 755 or 750.
All files should be 644 or 640. Exception: wp-config.php should be 440 or 400 to prevent other users on the server from reading it.
No directories should ever be given 777, even upload directories. Since the PHP process is running as the owner of the files, it gets the owners permissions and can write to even a 755 directory.

Run the following commands in your root folder and try to update your WordPress again.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: As per @leymannx's comments, you cannot assume `www-data` for the user and group as the OP may have something else.

Comment: right :). I think I should remove that code then.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to switch SELinux into Permissive mode:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

You will most likely want to set the mode back when you are done.